# Instrumentation amplifier using folded cascode op-amp is not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, instrumentation-amplifier, cascode

I made the sizing for a folded cascode operational amplifier, which is working well, however when I am trying to implement an instrumentation amplifier in LTspice using the blocks, it does not amplify the signal the right way.
This is the schematic which I try to implement:

[image]

This is the output voltage:

[image]

I made the sizing as such: R=R1=100Kohms and R2=17700Kohms, for a gain of 51dB.
So for the input I apply a sinewave with 10mV amplitude and a frequency of 34 Hz. So for the above parameters I should get an output of 3.55V, but instead I get a rectangular wave with 1.7V amplitude.
Implemented schematic in LTspice.
[image]

Folded cascode schematic:
[image]

Output and Input waveforms.

[image]

Thank you for reading and your help, I suppose I made some wrong connections in the schematic.

Comment: Test each op-amp block in isolation and see that you get what you require i.e. break the problem down to smaller chunks. And, input a smaller signal until the output is linear i.e. use your imagination to fault-find the problem.

Comment: Your power supply has only a range of 3.3V, it is impossible you'll get 3.55V output.

Comment: In addition to George Guo's comment, 17.7 M\$\Omega\$ is very large, and may not work with a real op-amp even if it works in simulation. With this resistance, you get very little feedback, and you are almost running your op-amps in open loop. Ideal op-amps have linear open-loop amplification. Real op-amps have very non-linear open-loop amplification, but feedback linearizes the closed loop amplification. The small amount of feedback in your case may not linearize your output very much.